# Configuring new table to EntityFramework(Core) in .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have added a new table to the localDB called ChatLog where I store chat messages and I have created 3 stored procedures for the table.

I've been looking online on how to configure that table for Entity Framework but I can't find a solution that works for me, I've even tried the override work arounds but usually there's an error revolving around DbContext that's not pulled from services.

I'm new at this and don't really know what I should do, and as I said, tutorials arent really helping since I lack the knowledge.

could some one give me a hand here? the table looks like this:

```
Column      | type
----------------------------
SenderId    | nvarchar(256)
RecipientId | nvarchar(256)
Message     | ntext
Time        | date
```

I have tried writing this, but it doesn't work:

```
[Table("ChatLog")]
public class ChatMessage
{
    [Required]
    [Column("SenderId")]
    public string SenderId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("RecipientId")]
    public string RecipientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("Time")]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

class ChatLogContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChatMessage>()
            .ToTable("ChatLog");
    }
}
```

Comment: which entity framework you are using `Data First Approach` or `Model First Approach` ?

Comment: I.. don't know. I made the table myself then realized I have to use EF to access the data.. so I would say, Data First

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your `.edmx` file for apply database changes, Please follow the below steps to update your table :

To update the `.edmx` file when the database changes :

1) Open your `.edmx` file by simply clicking on.

2) When the `.edmx` file is opened then simply right click on select `Update Model from Database`.

The Update Model Wizard starts. If there is no database connection specified, the Choose Your Database Connection dialog box appears. Otherwise, the Choose Your Database Objects dialog box appears.

3) If the Choose Your Database Connection dialog box appears, specify a database connection. Otherwise, go to the next step.

4) Click the `Add` tab.

5) Expand the `Tables`, `Views`, and `Stored Procedures` nodes, and check the objects you want to add to the `.edmx` file.

6) Click Finish to update the `.edmx` file with the database changes.

after applying this you will get your desired Table in your .edmx file.

Hope it helps you.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: ok.. use this link for your refrence :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4923b7/creating-a-edmx-file-using-entity-data-model/

Comment: AND I don't have ADO.NET Entity Data Model in my templates.. Everything else runs perfectly, as the users database fills up, but I can't to the bottom of that to see how it's connected

Comment: When I open the templates I only have ASP.NET, Clientside and Code as template categories.